# Adding 50 digit arrays in java

Tags: arrays, integer, digits

I'm new to java. Please help me.

I want a program that adds two integers of up to 50 digits each representing integer as an array of digits in java.

I tried to add two arrays taking 50 elements in each array but that is not even close.
I don't even want to show the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use java.math.BigInteger class. This class can handle arbitrary-precision integer.

By "50 digits", I assume you mean in decimal. so you can initialize your BigInteger with BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.TEN.

addition can be done with BigInteger.add(BigInteger val) function.

See document at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html for details.